# TextEdit: Simple JS code snippet throws exception

Tags: javascript, safari, textedit

I just tried to write some little js code piece. I use macs TextEdit (until I choose a better editor). Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body><script type="text/javascript">
console.log(„Hello World!“);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I try to open that snippet in Safari then I get the message:

> [Error] SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u8222' (anonymous function)
>   (index.html, line 6)

In my opinion should line 6 be ok, what is my mistake? Could it be because of TextEdit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JavaScript strings must be quoted with the simple `"` or `'` characters.

Comment: Get a proper code editor.

Comment: Go get Sublime or or a real IDE like Brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i could solve the problem. There are two settings which you need to set in TextEdit:

1. new document/format -> change to plain text
2. new document/options -> deactivate "intelligent quotation marks"

Then it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, TextEdit is turning your double-quotes into fancy-double-quotes.  Under the Format menu, use Make Plain Text.

Comment: Thanks very much, I changed to plan text but unfortunately the script still doesn't work and I get the same error.

Comment: After changing format, did you correct the quotes and re-save?

Comment: Yes, I even created a complete new file and wrote the code again. What I did notice: The beginning quotes are still going up and I have to post-correct them. So I guess there is still a format problem.

Comment: If you create a new file, you need to repeat Make Plain Text.  Alternatively, under Preferences -> New Text Document -> Format, select Plain Text and then all new files will be plain text by default.

Comment: I also did that. I changed the preferences so all new files are plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
console.log(„Hello World!“);
```

Use

```
console.log("Hello World!");
```

If you are using your editor in wrong format go to settings to change your formats